# Java resolve project path

Tags: java, eclipse, path

I am trying to return my project's file path to then create a file in said path. I successfully created the file in the path but I used the static path to my project rather than resolving it programatically  like I need to do.

Using the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html) i've tried creating my file:

```
    Path path = Paths.get("C:\\folder\\folder\\folder\\folder\\folder\\report\\");
    String filePath = path.toString() + "fileName.pdf";
    createFile(filePath, data, moreData);
```

**Question:**

What if someone else uses a D: drive or other? How do I resolve the report folder if that is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relative path to the file, rather than an absolute path.

```
Path path = Paths.get("reports/fileName.pdf");
String filePath = path.toString() + "fileName.pdf";
createFile(filePath, data, moreData);
```

Comment: The file does not exist yet, I am creating it at the path.

Comment: You can still create a new file at a relative path. Any sub-directories will have to already exist, unless you manually create them in the application. But as long as the directory exists, you can write a new File to a directory specified by a relative path.

Comment: I will test this shortly

Comment: `Path path = Paths.get("/reports/fileName.pdf");` did not work.

Comment: Remove the leading slash to make it a relative path.

Comment: `Path path = Paths.get("reports/fileName.pdf");` works, please update your answer.

Comment: If you meant the leading slash, my answer didn't have a leading slash to begin with :-)

Comment: `Path path = Paths.get("reports/fileName.pdf");` is the answer I needed, not a `String`